# How to send a message from one node to another node in Erlang OTP

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, erlang-otp

We can send a message to an existing process via the shell as below. I register a process by its Username here (ex: alice)
code:

```
start_link(Username) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, Username}, ?MODULE, [Username], []).

stop(Username)->
  gen_server:stop(Username).

init([Username]) ->
  io:format("~p connected...",[Username]),
  {ok, #chat_server_state{
    username = Username
  }}.
```

Process started as below:

```
chat_client:start_link(alice).
alice connected...{ok,<0.143.0>}
```

I sent message hello to process alice and result as below:

```
alice ! hello. %%sent 'hello' atom to 'alice' process
hello   %% result
```

My problem is if I started two nodes with same coockie and connected both nodes with net_kernel, still why I cant send a message from one node to other node using the registered process name (instead of pid) as above procedure.

my code: here I register the process with the node name.

```
start_link(Username) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, node()}, ?MODULE, [Username], []).

stop(Username)->
  gen_server:stop(Username).

init([Username]) ->
  io:format("~p connected...",[Username]),
  {ok, #chat_server_state{
    username = Username
  }}.
```

I started alice process on alice@... node.

```
(alice@DESKTOP-RD414DV)79> chat_client:start_link(alice).
alice connected...{ok,<0.280.0>}
```

This is where this alice process is registered with its node name

```
** Registered procs on node 'alice@DESKTOP-RD414DV' **
Name                  Pid          Initial Call                      Reds Msgs
'alice@DESKTOP-RD414D <0.250.0>    chat_client:init/1                  54    0
```

Why can't I send a message from this alice@..... node to another node (ex: bob@DESKTOP-RD414D by **'bob@DESKTOP-RD414D' ! hello.** )

```
(alice@DESKTOP-RD414DV)71> whereis('alice@DESKTOP-RD414DV').                
<0.250.0>
```

I get this error:

```
(alice@DESKTOP-RD414DV)50> 'bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV' ! heelo.
** exception error: bad argument
     in operator  !/2
        called as 'bob@DESKTOP-RD414DV' ! heelo
```

Comment: I leave this as a comment because it's unrelated to the question, and you may already have it into account: Using atoms as usernames is not a good idea because atoms are not freed ever, any new atom is an entry in the atoms table, which is permanently extended.

Comment: Thank you.So, Is it better to use the node name as the process name ?. If the process is registered as the node name, then Can I use that node name instead of the PID for any purpose ? or there is a way to give a name for PID replacing <0.250.0> ?

Comment: How to do the same remotely between two nodes?

Comment: I think I did not explain myself correctly: You can (and should) use atom names for distinguished processes in the node. The problem arises when you try to spawn and register atom-named processes for each (chat) user's connection: Once created an atom lives forever.
Instead, you should use something like the ETS/mnesia to store the `chat_username -> pid` relationship, making sure to clean any records that point to dead processes and either replicate the table or broadcast the messages throughout the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a message to a registered process in any node, you can use the `{Name :: atom(), Node :: node()} ! Message :: term()` syntax:

```
1> register(shell, self()).
true
2> shell ! test.
test
3> flush().
Shell got test
ok
4> {shell, node()} ! test.
test
5> flush().
Shell got test
ok
```